# Store objects in CSV file without changing their class to string

Tags: ruby, class, csv

I'm storing some recipe instances in a CSV file like this:

```
def add_recipe(recipe)
  CSV.open(@filepath, 'ab', @csv_options) do |csv|
    csv << [recipe, recipe.name, recipe.description, false]
  end
end
```

with `recipe` being an intense of my `Recipe` class. 
In the file, I have something like this:

```
"#<Recipe:0x007fee9bbbab48>", "name1", "description1", "false"
"#<Recipe:0x007fee9bbbab49>", "name2", "description2", "false"
```

The issue is that when I want to retrieve the object stored in each row with `row[0]` or the boolean with `row[2]`, I get a string containing the object or the boolean.

How can I get the object with its original class which is Recipe or boolean but not as a string?

Comment: Why the down vote  ? The question is detailed and I added my code. The fact that it is not possible shouldn't justify a down vote ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. It is impossible with CSV (unless you invent your own serialization method for CSV). .........................

Comment: Do we need our *own* serialization? Ruby comes with the `Marshal` class, which possibly (depending on the exact requirements of the serialization) be used to serialize the data.

Comment: @user1934428 `Marshal` does not output as a CSV.

Comment: This is not necessary, @sawa. The requirement is to store a Ruby object in a (field of a) CSV file and retrieve it later. You marshal it, which serializes the object into a string, and store the resulting string into the respective field of the CSV file. You just have to pay attention of the CSV field separator, i.e. some additional quoting might be needed.

Answer (score 1):

What you have stored in the first column is the result of `recipe.to_s`, which is nothing more than a string with the class type and an encoding of the object id. This is not the same as a serialized object.

You have to write each attribute of the recipes as you have already done, and not write `recipe` itself to a line.

```
csv << [recipe.id, recipe.name, recipe.description, recipe.other_attribute]
```

Comment: That only works for attributes that are strings. It won't work for example with `"false"` that OP has.